# Getting warning message "WARNING in Entry point '@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to' contains deep imports into 'rxjs/index'"

Tags: typescript, angular8

I am following the article provided at below URL:

[Pluggable Enterprise Application with angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/building-extensible-dynamic-pluggable-enterprise-application-with-angular-aed8979faba5)

The code repository is provided below:
[Github Code Repository](https://github.com/alexzuza/angular-plugin-architecture). This code is written using Angular 7. I decided to add one more plugin which has host as well as windows scrolling in it. For this, I use the module "[@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to)". And I change to Angular 8.0.3 version. After making these changes and when I try to build my plugins again, then I start getting below warnings:

> WARNING in Entry point '@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to' contains deep
>   imports into 'rxjs/index'. This is probably not a problem, but may
>   cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order

And immediately after this warning, build process get the exit.
Please let me know, where I am getting wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the `ngx-scroll-to` error, previously plugin was not compatible with `angular-8` but they have upgraded it [see here](https://github.com/nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to/issues/121). so you just need to update the package to the latest version.